# How to test foursquare api in application without a public URL

Tags: foursquare

Hi I am trying to develop an application for iphone using the Foursquare API, this application  will be a set of tools that will interact with a ASP.NET application and also the same ios application in android and windows phone 7.

The issue here is that the push part of the api requires and URL to do the push and I don't have a url yet and if I created that url now, how can I change when all the tool set goes live?

The idea is I should be available to test all part of this tool set without buy an domain, url etc.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

JV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always edit your app's [settings](https://foursquare.com/developers/apps) (including push URL) at any time, but Foursquare can't send a push notification to a non-public URL. If you currently don't have a public URL and are running everything locally, something like [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/) may be useful to you.

Comment: Nice tool, is there something like for windows?